# ASP.net Searching from Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, search

I am developing an app in which i need to give searching option to user like if user enters 'scienc' the search functions should get the courses with name science or if in their description science like word occurs, i mean to say if user enters half word query should get full word by matching characters sequence but i don't know how to implement this and i am using Entity Framework in my application.

One thing more i need to search from multiple tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: search for ajax auto fill will solve your problem

Comment: Off the top of my head you could use the Full Text Search feature in SQL Server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx then create a custom stored procedure and use the DbCommand to execute it and return results http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/03/26/ado-entity-framework-stored-procedure-customization.aspx

Comment: furthering @RahulVasantraoKamble's answer try this popular tool [Jquery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want to implement AUto complete if so then following code will solved out your problem:

Code file:

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string[] GetPatientLastName(string prefix)
{
    List<string> customers = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        string connectionstring = CCMMUtility.GetCacheForWholeApplication();
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionstring;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select distinct top(10) PatientLastname from tblMessage where  " +
            "PatientLastname  like '%'+ @SearchText + '%' order by PatientLastname";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(string.Format("{0}", sdr["PatientLastname"]));
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return customers.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[ID$=txtPatientLastname]').live('keyup.autocomplete', function () {

            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Resources/WebService.asmx/GetPatientLastName") %>',
                        data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.split('-')[0],
                                    val: item.split('-')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (e, i) {
                },
                minLength: 1
            });
        });
});
```

Hope this will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: thanks raman but sorry to say i have to search from 4 tables and if i found results in 2 or 3 tables matching the word i have to show all.. help me if you have any idea.

Comment: that logic will come in database's process... this step is after that... you need to implement the joins in db query to fetch data from  more than 1 table..